# Calculate Spearman's Rank Correlation Coefficient

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

there!

I'm trying to calculate correlations using [this method](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Spearman%27s-Rank-Correlation-Coefficient).

However, when I do the math by hand, I get one result, and when I do it with R - `cor(dt, use="complete.obs", method="spearman")` -  I get totally different thing.

Example data below:

```
---------------------------------
AnswerPosID.1007 AnswerPosID.1008
---------------------------------
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                2
               1                2
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               2                1
               2                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
               1                1
---------------------------------
```

Manual result: 0.799777530589544;

R cor: -0.07142857

Comment: How did you break ties in the ranks when you did this by hand?

Comment: you really did this by hand? these numbers aren't correlated at all, so I would question how you got .8. Kudos for the precision, though.

Comment: Both R and the correl function in Excel give -0.07, so I think that the problem is with calculating it by hand.

Comment: @rawr, they are if you choose a particular method for breaking ties in ranks. For example, if you do `cor(rank(var1, ties = "first"), rank(var2, ties = "first))` you get `0.86`. That said, none of the tie-breaking options in `rank()` gives what the OP computed by hand. (And I do actually agree with your main point, I just wanted to highlight the issue of ties and that the result you get is highly dependant upon how you handle them.) The data look categorical so perhaps a correlative method more appropriate for such data should be used?

Comment: I should have mentioned, that I have absolutely no idea what I am doing - it is something from my job. It's not exactly "by hand" - we use some SQL script to calculate these values. And it is literally blindly following the wikihow's method. Which gives me a second question - in our script, the "1" and "2" are sorted by value (ascending) - does this matter? Again it produces different result. Later I'll give you in-depth mid-results we receive (now it's weekend)

Comment: Here are the calculations: http://pastebin.com/rGEXw0YC
A lot different than R